# How do I use the output of pandas.ewm.cov?

Tags: python, pandas

How is one intended to use the output of the `pandas.ewm.cov` function.  I would presume that there are functions that allow you to directly use it in the form returned for multiplication, but nothing I try seems to work.

For example, suppose I take a minimal use case, stock X and Y returns timeseries in DF1, so we estimate an ewma covariance matrix, then to get the variance estimate for a portfolio of position A and B (given in DF2) I need to compute $x^T C x$, but I can't find the command to do this without writing a for loop?

```
# Python 3.6,  pandas 0.20
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(X = np.random.normal(size = 100), Y = np.random.normal(size = 100)))
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = np.random.normal(size = 100), B = np.random.normal(size = 100)))
COV = DF1.ewm(10).cov()

print(DF1)
print(COV)

# All of the following are invalid
print(COV.dot(DF2)) 
print(DF2.dot(COV)) 
print(COV.multiply(DF2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can figure out is this ugly piece of code

```
COV.reset_index().rename(columns = dict(level_0 = "index", level_1 = "variable"), inplace = True)
DF2m = pd.melt(DF2.reset_index(), id_vars = "index").sort_values("index")
MDF = pd.merge(COV, DF2m, on=["index", "variable"])
VAR = MDF.groupby("index").apply(lambda x: np.dot(np.dot(x["value"], np.matrix([x["X"], x["Y"]])), x["value"])[0,0])
```

I hold out hope that there is a nice way to do this...